Azure MSAL React apps using same authentication/user across multiple apps
I have multiple separate React apps using @azure/msal-react for authentication. They are both single-tenant (the same tenant) apps.
However, some of our users (mainly admins) have multiple Microsoft user accounts. When they log into one site (SPA 1), that account is automatically used for the other site (SPA 2).
Here is how they are configured:
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: ***EACH SITE HAS A UNIQUE CLIENT ID***,
    authority: ***EACH SITE HAS THE SAME AUTHORITY URL***,
    redirectUri: ***EACH SITE HAS A UNIQUE REDIRECT URI,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
  }
}

Basically if they have logged in with any account with this tenant in the same browser, it carries over to all other sites, but I don't want that to happen.

Login process works well, outside of this case.
Expectation is for user to log in with whatever Microsoft account they want for each site and store that specific site's auth state in localStorage across browser sessions.


I created two separate React apps using @azure/msal-react for authentication.
Even I got the same issue when I tried your code.
I've used prompt parameter to the login request object in your code.
prompt:"select_account"
export  const  loginRequest  = {
scopes: ["User.Read"],
prompt:  "select_account"
};


This will ensure the user has to select or enter their credentials each time.

This is my complete authConfig.js:
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
      clientId: 'your-client-id',
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-id',
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage', 
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false,   
    }
  };
  export const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["User.Read"],
    prompt: "select_account" 
  };  

This is App.js file:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { loginRequest } from './authConfig';

const App = () => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Local Storage:', localStorage);
  }, []);

  const handleLogin = () => {
    instance.loginPopup(loginRequest).catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    });
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    instance.logoutPopup().catch(e => {
      console.error(e);
    }).finally(() => {
      localStorage.clear();  
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Site</h1>
      {accounts.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <p>Welcome, {accounts[0].name}</p>
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={handleLogin}>Login</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


Output:
SITE A:


SITE B:
Here, Site B is handling authentication independently.


All this is really doing is changing the storage location from localStorage to sessionStorage.
I want to keep the localStorage functionality for across browser tabs of a single site, and across multiple sessions without having to log in every time.
The goal is to log in to SITE 1 and store that auth data in localStorage, then open SITE 2 and do the same (possibly with a different account).

I actually have it working now with localStorage.
I think the problem was that I was not passing in anything to instance.loginRedirect(). Now here's what I have:
instance.loginRedirect({         scopes: ['user.read'],         prompt: 'select_account',       })
The 'select_account' property seems to give me the functionality that I was after.
I really appreciate it!
If you want to remove the sessionStorage parts, I will mark this answer as correct. That part isn't wrong per say, but unnecessary for this solution. Goal was to retain localStorage features.

@swwjjj_ok as per your suggestion I've updated my solution, please check.
